# TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable while iterating over dict by date

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over dict, which contains dates as keys:

```
for d, dir in subdirs:
    print("d=", d, ", dir=", dir)
```

where subdirs is

```
datetime.date(2016, 9, 29): ['tiles/37/U/DB/2016/9/29/0/'],datetime.date(2017, 2, 23): ['tiles/37/U/DB/2017/2/23/0/'], datetime.date(2016, 4, 5): ['tiles/37/U/DB/2016/4/5/0/']
```

and so on.

I am receiving

> TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable

Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this -

```
for d, dir in subdirs.items():
    print("d=", d, ", dir=", dir)
```

If `subdirs` is a dict, using it in `for` will give you only the keys(in your case `datetime.date` object) and `d, dir` will try to unpack them. That is why the error.

Using the `items()` will return the `(key, value)` pair which will be unpacked and stored in `d` and `dirs` respectively